# How to check Html String Print Preview in Windows Form C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have to create a form for `Print Preview`, in which i have to show the text which i want to Print, that text withing a string variable with html tags for example like this-:

```
String TextToPrint = "<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>
```

**Now how i can show print preview of this Html String, without showing the Html tags.**

Comment: you can show in richtext control of window form

Comment: You've tagged the question with both ASP.NET and WinForms, which is it?

Comment: i am doing it in Winforms

Comment: Do you have the string from before the HTML markup was added? Are you expecting any formatting to be performed?

Comment: Off course, i want the output in formatting format, for example if i am writing like this <b>Hello</b> This Hello should be bold.

Comment: Did you add the HTML in the expectation that formatting would be performed for you, or does the string already have the HTML in it?

Comment: Sting already have the HTML, eg. String CodeToPrint="<html><body><b>Hello</b></body></html>